# Protractor shows variable value as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

We are defining variables from the elements on one page of the website, clicking on the edit button, which is opening the next page. In this page we need to assert that the data captured on the earlier page matches the data shown on the 2nd page. Our problem is, once the test moves to the 2nd page, it fails to recall the variables that we defined on the 1st page. below is our code snippets:

```
     it ('Student ID Validation', function(){

        // get rows
        var rows = tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr"));

        // get cell values
        var cells = rows.all(by.tagName("td"));

        var Student_ID = cells.get(0).getText().then(function(SID){
            console.log(SID);
        });
    Edit_Button_1.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    expect(Student_ID_on_Reg_Page.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(Student_ID);
```

after execution, we get the following error

```
 Message:
Expected '123456' to equal undefined.
```

We were suspecting that it may be due to asynchronization, but that is not the case. the test moves to page 2 after it stores the variable from page 1, so we are at a loss why this is happening. How can we fix this and use the variables for assertion purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've specified the `then()` callback where you just log the value but don't return it:

```
var Student_ID = cells.get(0).getText().then(function(SID){
    console.log(SID);
});
```

As nothing is returned, `Student_ID` would become a promise which would resolve into `undefined`.

You either need a return:

```
var Student_ID = cells.get(0).getText().then(function(SID){
    console.log(SID);
    return SID;
});
```

Or, remove the custom callback completely:

```
var Student_ID = cells.get(0).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what we were missing.

Answer (score 0):

actually, the following part is causing the problem. Once we removed this part, the test is working fine.

`.then(function(SID){
            console.log(SID);
        });`

Comment: be careful with that. It may not work all the time. To understand what I mean research the difference of promises with asynchronous functions in JS